# .NET MAUI iOS Transfer-Encoding: identity in Response Header

Tags: ios, .net, maui

I have the following scenario: An application in Xamarin.Forms for Android and iOS that communicates with a GraphQL server for data synchronization. On both platforms, messages are exchanged with the server via REST with `Transfer-Encoding: chunked`.

I also have another application, in .NET MAUI, which uses the same synchronization service.

In this second application, the Android platform exchanges messages with the server with `Transfer-Encoding: chunked` and **everything works perfectly**. Now, for the iOS platform, messages exchanged with the synchronization service return with `Transfer-Encoding: identity` and it does not work.

What can I adjust in my MAUI for iOS app so that everything works normally?

*Note that there is no need to change the synchronization server code.*